# creating javascript array then passing to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, google-maps

Taught myself PHP to build some basic site stuff, now I fear that I am getting in too deep. I have searched relentlessly and couldn't figure out the following:

I am looking to get a list returned of latitude/longitude markers from Google Maps into an array and pass it over to PHP. In theory I should be able to handle it... but so far when I try to modify this (code below) to array push or something alike it breaks...so I guess I am ways off.

Here is the bit that is currently generating an HTML list of latitude/longitude points.

```
 for (var key in markers) {
     var obj = markers[key];
     if (markers[key].hasOwnProperty("position")) {
        document.getElementById("waypoints").innerHTML += markers[key].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) +"<br>";
    }
  }
```

Once I go into PHP, I will explore the array and use the latitude/longitude to search for nearby items.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you have JavaScript elements you need to pass to PHP you should do it with AJAX.

Comment: you need to perform asyncronous requests to pass elements from javascript to php, since javascript is a **client side language** and is executed AFTER php, which is a **server side language**, hence you have to pass a variable either through a form (by refreshing the page) OR through an ajax request (by NOT refreshing the page). A great API to simplify your job (for AJAX requests) is jQuery, which is a comfortable javascript library that will surely help you to keep your logic in your javascript file..

Comment: Can you use jquery? Maybe http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I think I can figure the passing via ajax part..i was also thinking of posting to a new page would be fine..but formatting the javascript from html into an array is the part im stuck on right now

Comment: Why don't you send the `markers` or the `obj` variable instead or generate a new array / object in the inner `if` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pathToPhpFileThatWillReceiveArray.php",
    data: markers,
    type: "post or get"
}).success(function(returnedResult){
    doSmtWithReturnedResult();
}).error(function(xhr, statur, error){ 
    doSmt(); 
});
```

Comment: no, it has to be another php-file where the php-code receives the `data` from the ajax, operates on them, and returns a json back to js, and that will be the `returnedResult` in the success-function

Comment: but the user will still stay on the current page! it's just your ajax call that will send and get smt back from a different file without changing the current page for the user.